# springboot project deploy with gradle : Execution failed for task ':deploytest'

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I write a springboot project with gradle, and I want to deploy it.

Here comes part of my code in `build.gradle` :

```
remotes {
  localtest {
    host = '192.168.0.116'
    user = 'root'
    password = '*****'
  }
}

task deploytest(dependsOn: build) << {
  ssh.run {
    session(remotes.localtest) {
      put from: 'build/libs/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar', into: '/opt/test/'
      execute "cd /opt/tieba"
      execute 'nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar & echo $! > application.pid'
    }
  }
}
```

Then I run `gradle deploytest`, but it meets a problem :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\github\spring-projects\test\build.gradle' line: 97

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deploytest'.
> reject HostKey: 192.168.0.116
```

---

Details

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':deploytest'.

Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: reject HostKey: 192.168.0.116

[gradle error details 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPqX4.png)
 [gradle error details 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Trs.png)

Comment: can you login to this host from terminal?

Comment: Is the public key of the server already in your known_hosts file? Could this be the problem you are facing: http://anahorny.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/solution-for-comjcraftjschjschexception.html ?

Comment: @DavidTanzer thanks for your answer, it helped a lot !!!

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue, the server was using ED25519.

I deleted the corresponding line in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, retrieved the rsa banner with `ssh-keyscan -t rsa myserver.tld` and copied the result back to `known_host`

Looks better than setting `knownHosts = allowAnyHosts`

Comment: `ssh-keyscan -t rsa server.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by setting `knownHosts = allowAnyHosts` in ssh config, complete setting is

```
remotes {
   localtest {
     host = '192.168.0.116' 
     user = 'root' 
     knownHosts = allowAnyHosts 
     password = '*****' 
   }
}
```